# Escaping Body of POST with + signs in the data converts them to spaces

Tags: xcode, api, urlencode

I am sending data to a server, it all works fine but the if there is a plus sign in there it gets converted to a space.  (Note there is an entire JSON string but I have just copied out the phone number I am trying to encode)

I am encoding the data using;

```
[result stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]
```

Encoding : "+44(0) 7811 222 3335 55666"

Produces : "+44%20(0)%207811%20222%203335%2055666"

The plus sign is then replaced by a space when sent to the server (as it is not escaped).

My workaround is nasty

```
// URL Encode
result = [result stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

// Convert the plus sign ------ nasty
result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

Result is; %2B44%20(0)%207811%20222%203335%2055666

And decode;

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Convert the plus sign ------ nasty
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%2B" withString:@"+"];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] options:0 error:nil];
```